# Compute unique ID for a video DVD

Tags: vlc, disk, libvlc, identification, dvd

I'm trying to find a way to generate a unique ID for specific versions of a video DVD.

For example, if you have 2 identical copies of **The Matrix** DVD, inserting either DVD should output the exact same ID because they both represent the same content, release, country of origin, etc.

[This forum post](https://sourceforge.net/p/lsdvd/mailman/message/32898100/) mentions using libdvdread's [DVDDiscID()](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/libdvdread/blob/master/src/dvd_reader.c#L1399) method, which appears to do what I want. However, I can't find a CLI or binaries to use. It appears that the VideoLan project has taken ownership of libdvdread, is it possible to use the VLC binaries/cli to call `libdvdread.DVDDiscID()`?

Is there a command-line utility already out there that can generate some type of unique ID for a video DVD? If not, how can I use libdvdread (or some other similar free library) in a NodeJS, PHP, C#, Python or C++ application on a Windows computer to get this information?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like what you want https://github.com/beandog/dvd_info, it depends on libdvdread. Or just compile libdvdread and call it from your app.

Comment: Thanks. I need it work on windows though, and according to the project's github page, it only works on Linux. Do you know of any resources showing how to compile libdvdread on a windows machine?

Comment: Use docker https://code.videolan.org/videolan/libdvdread/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml#L40 or grab a CI build https://code.videolan.org/videolan/libdvdread/pipelines/3305

Comment: Thanks, those are both very helpful! For the CI build, I'm not having much luck finding how to download the build artifacts (so I don't have to compile from source myself). Am I missing the "download" option somewhere or are there no build artifacts?